# Unable to create a type-level list with a single element

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

I'm scratching my head with the following behaviour. Is there an obvious reason why this is the case?

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds

Prelude> :k 'True
'True :: Bool

Prelude> :k ['True, 'False]
['True, 'False] :: [Bool]

Prelude> :k ['True]

<interactive>:1:2: error:
    • Expected a type, but ‘ 'True’ has kind ‘Bool’
    • In the type ‘[ 'True]’
```

PS: I'm on GHC 8.4.3 if this is a GHC bug and was fixed later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to disambiguate list types from type level list types by the backtick:

```
> :k '[ 'True]
```

Also note the space after `[`, which is needed to disambiguate from type-level character literals.

Comment: So, `:k ['True, 'False]` just _happens_ to work because of some relaxed parsing rules?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda: yes.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Well... it's not just coincidence or something. The comma in `['True, 'False]` makes it clear that it's not the list type former but an actual list.